# Get FK of previous formset and pass into the Next one

Tags: python, django, formset, inlines

I'm Working on a project and i'm trying to make a product variation,

I have a Product, a Color Variation (FK=Product) and a Size Variation (FK=Color Variation)

**I'm using inline formsets to acomplished that, but when i save more then one Color Variation, i get error saying that get() returned 2 objects.**

On my CreateView form_valid, first i save the product, then i loop into the variants and inside this loop i made another loop to save the sizes.

So for example, if i have Color Red, it will save, then loop to all the sizes that belong to color red and save, and after will check for another Color variation.**But this only works when i have only 1 color variation**

**How can i get the fk of the variation that is beeing looped and pass to the size ?**

Here are my CreateView:

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        ctx = super(ProductCreate, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        if self.request.POST:
            ctx['variants'] = VariantFormSet(self.request.POST or None, self.request.FILES or None, prefix='variants')
            ctx['sizes']    = SizeFormSet(self.request.POST or None, self.request.FILES or None, prefix='sizes')
        else: 
            ctx['variants'] = VariantFormSet(prefix='variants')
            ctx['sizes'] = SizeFormSet(prefix='sizes')
        return ctx

def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.vendor          = get_vendor(self.request)
        form.instance.product_slug    = slugify(form.instance.product_name)
        
        context         = self.get_context_data()
        variants        = context['variants']
        sizes           = context['sizes']
        with transaction.atomic():
            self.object = form.save()
            if variants.is_valid():
                for variant in variants:
                    variant.instance.product = self.object                
                    variant.save()
                    
                    if sizes.is_valid():
                        for size in sizes:
                            size.instance.product = Variant.objects.get(product=self.object)
                            size.save()
            
                
                return redirect('product_list')
```

Models.py

```
class Product(models.Model):
    vendor                      = models.ForeignKey(UserVendor, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    category                    = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product_name                = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)

class Variant(models.Model):
    product                     = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product_color               = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    product_color_code          = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True , null=True)
    product_price               = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True)
    product_stock               = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)

class Size(models.Model):
    product                     = models.ForeignKey(Variant, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    size_name                   = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
    size_stock                  = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    size_price                  = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True)
```

Forms.py

```
class ProductForm(forms.ModelForm):
    product_name                  = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form__input'}))
    product_description           = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'class':'form__input'}))
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = {'product_name','product_description','category','is_available'}
       
class SizeForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Size
        fields = '__all__'

class VariantForm(forms.ModelForm):    
    class Meta:
        model = Variant
        fields = '__all__'

VariantFormSet = inlineformset_factory(
    Product, Variant, form = VariantForm,
    extra=1, can_delete=True, can_delete_extra=True
)

SizeFormSet = inlineformset_factory(
    Variant, Size, form = SizeForm,
    extra=1, can_delete=True, can_delete_extra=True
)
```

I already try to check for nested inline, and django-extra-views, but i couldnt make it work with dynamic add from jquery